# How can I split a column off of a DataFrame, but keep its association with the initial DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe `dataDF` that is:

```
+-------+------+-----+-----+-----------+
|TEST_PK| COL_1|COL_2|COL_3|h_timestamp|
+-------+------+-----+-----+-----------+
|      1| apple|   10| 1.79|       1111|
|      1| apple|   11| 1.79|       1114|
|      2|banana|   15| 1.79|       1112|
|      2|banana|   16| 1.79|       1115|
|      3|orange|    7| 1.79|       1113|
+-------+------+-----+-----+-----------+
```

And I need to run this function:
`operation(row, h_timestamp)`
On each row, but `row` can not contain `h_timestamp`, so my first thought is to split the dataframe like:

```
val columns = dataDF.drop("h_timestamp")  
val timestamp = dataDF.select("h_timestamp")
```

But that doesn't help when I want to perform the operation on every row like:

```
dataDF.map(row => {
  ...
  val rowWithoutTimestamp = ???
  val timestamp = ???
  operation(rowWithoutTimestamp, timestamp)
  ...
})
```

But now those two dataframes are not linked and I don't know how to get the right timestamp for each row. The `TEST_PK` column is not necessarily unique.
Is there a way to use `.drop()` or `.select()` on just a row or some other way to do this?
Edit: Also, the table could have any number of columns, but will always have the timestamp column and at least one more that is not the timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have what appears to be a primary key column, just fork the timestamp with the id column into it's own dataframe to re-join it later.

```
val tsDF = dataDF.select("TEST_PK", "h_timestamp")
```

Then, drop the column from `dataDF`, do your operation, and re-join the h_timestamp back onto a new dataframe.

```
val finalDF = postopDF.join(tsDF, "TEST_PK")
```

**Update**

The sample code is helpful, you should be able to essentially dissasemble your row, and rebuild a new row with the desired values with something like this:

```
dataDF.map(row => {
  val rowWithoutTimestamp = Row(
    row.getAs[Long]("TEST_PK"),
    row.getAs[String]("COL_1"),
    row.getAs[Long]("COL_2"),
    row.getAs[Double]("COL_3")
  )
  val timestamp = row.getAs[Long]("h_timestamp")
  val result = operation(rowWithoutTimestamp, timestamp)
  Row(result, timestamp)
})
```

Of course, I'm not certain what your `operation()` returns, so it may be necessary to disassemble `result` into individual values and compose a new row with those and the timestamp.

**Update 2**

OK, here is a more generic method. It wraps "all columns except" `h_timestamp` into a struct, and maps over the `(struct, ts)` tuple. Actually more elegant than the previous solution anyway.

```
val cols = df.drop("h_timestamp").columns.toSeq
dataDF
  .select(struct(cols.map(c => col(c)):_*).as("row_no_ts"), $"h_timestamp")
  .map(row => {
    val rowWithoutTimestamp = row.getAs[Row]("row_no_ts")
    val timestamp = row.getAs[Long]("h_timestamp")
    operation(rowWithoutTimestamp, timestamp)
  })
```

I'm not sure if you are mapping to just the output of `operation()` or some combination with the timestamp again, but both are available to modify to suit your needs.

Comment: I've updated the question, the TEST_PK column is not necessarily a unique identifier

Comment: operation returns a string, so no need to worry about that. Is there a generic way to construct a row that can handle any number of columns? The table could be anything, but will always have the timestamp column and at least one more that is not the timestamp

Comment: @JaredDuPont See Update 2